# Creating filters based on dates ranges

Tags: tableau-api

I am new to Tableau and had a question about creating filters.  I have a data set that has a field called "Start Date" and a field called "End Date".  Using these two fields, I want to create a filter with the following options:

1. Records that have a "Start Date" prior to the current date, called "Pending Records"
2. Records that have an "End Data" after the current date, called "Expired Records"
3. Records that have a "Start Date" equal to or greater than the current date and have an "End Date" less than the current date, called "Active Records"

I would like this to be one filter, with those three choices.  Is this possible? If so, are there any examples I could look at?

FYI, I am using Tableau Desktop Version 10.3

thanks

**UPDATE**

I also had to add a status for "Records with an end date within 6 months", so I used this code:

```
IF 
(
[Start Date] > TODAY()  
) then "PendingRecord"
elseif (
[End Date] < TODAY() 
) then "ExpiredRecord" 
elseif (
[Start Date] <= TODAY() AND 
([End Date] > TODAY() AND
[End Date] > DATEADD("month",6, TODAY()))
) then "ActiveRecord"
elseif (
[Start Date] <= TODAY() AND 
([End Date] > TODAY() AND
[End Date] <= DATEADD("month",6, TODAY()))
) then "EndingIn6Months"
END
```

This creates a filter with 4 options. But, "EndingIn6Moths" is really a subset of ActiveRecord.  So, when a user selects ActiveRecords, it should also include EndingIn6Months.  Is this possible?  Is it possible to auto check a filter (EndingIn6Months) when the user checks ActiveREcords option?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following will help you.

1- Create a calculated field for current date : Now()

2- Create another calculated field

```
If  [Start Date] = [Now] then "Pending Records"
    ELSEIF      [END Date] = [Now] then "Pending Records"              
    ELSEIF      [Start Date] => [Now]  AND [END Date] < [Now] then "Active Records"                                                                     
    ELSE        "Others"
    END
```

Could you please share your workbook?

I feel like different rows will fall into different buckets. You will have cases when you will meet first and second condition.I think you would need to exclude them from each other.  It would be great to see the dataset.

Please let me know if any question.

Comment: Yes, this is what I ended up doing and it worked.  The issue is that my business owner also wants to denote records that have an End Date in the next 6 months.  I will add the code I used to get this, but what it does is split ActiveRecords into two groups, those ending in 6 months and those that are not.  This is fine, but this affects my filters. I will update my question to reflect my follow up question, though maybe its best in a new thread?